# How to difference a cylinder from the car body using Boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling

I have created a basic car body. Now, I'm trying to get the tires in place. What I am trying to do is to use a cylinder of 10 vertices with an *Array* modifier at *Count: 1* and *Relative Offset* set to mimic the cylinder on the other side. Then, I am using the *Boolean* modifier to subtract the cylinder from the car body. However, it produces strange results when I drag my cylinder out after applying.

Car Cube Modifiers:
Mirror
Subsurf
Boolean

Cylinder Modifiers:
Array

*Car body before applying the Boolean modifier:*

[image: Car]

.blend file from before applying the Boolean:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com please? Makes it easier for us to help you, as it's hard to understand what the problem is with that image.

Comment: @LostVeteran Before, please.

Comment: @ShadyPuck Done. There may be a wheel hanging around in that file, too :D

Comment: @LostVeteran I added an answer. Just noticed that I didn't fully read your comment, and I used the wheels to Boolean instead of a cylinder. However, you should be able to replicate my results with a cylinder without any additional info. If you do need the info, let me know and I will redo some of my answer. If my answer helps you, please consider marking it as accepted by selecting the checkmark in the upper, left-hand corner of it. It would help me greatly and make me very happy!

Comment: haha No worries, man. I want to figure out solution myself, anyways. I will try in Wireframe mode so, I don't mess up with back side. Maybe, it causes the issue. Don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting a result like this:

[image]

When you want a result like this:

[image]

For this, you need to use the following modifier stack for the wheels and apply all of the modifiers in order, top to bottom, for the car.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you had to spend time on this but, I just want to push the plane side inside in a curve shape so I can place my tire in it. Like a real car. Makes sense? I used a bigger cylinder than my tire.

P.S. I am pretty new to Blender (like 4 days) and I can't figure out any other method! :D

+1 for the try.

Comment: @LostVeteran OH! OK. I am going to lunch right now, but I should be able to do what you described in your comment later tonight.